# Laravel changing sorting of collection when sending mail (between constructor and build function call)

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3

this is laravel 5.3

when I preview the email using this:

```
    $wantsheet_products = WantsheetProduct::orderByRaw(EmailService::WANTSHEET_PRODUCT_ORDER_SQL)->get();
    View::make('email.wantsheet.email_wantsheet_to_supplier', ['wantsheet_products' => $wantsheet_products]);
```

the sorting is correct. that is, sorting is ['a','b','c'] the way i want it.

**EDIT** see note at the bottom

now when actually sending out the mails (i queue them), the sorting changed and is unsorted again, magic?! the change happens between the constructor and the build function

```
class WantsheetToSuppliersMail extends Mailable
{

  public $wantsheet_products;
  public $to_email;
  /** @var  WantsheetContact  $wantsheetcontact*/
  public $wantsheetcontact;
  use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($wantsheet_products)
    {
//$wantsheet_products is a standard eloquent model collection, e.g. i get it like this:  WantsheetProduct::orderByRaw(self::WANTSHEET_PRODUCT_ORDER_SQL)->get()
      $this->wantsheet_products = $wantsheet_products; //is ['a','b','c']
    }


    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

//      $this->wantsheet_products is ['b','a','c'];
      $subject = 'abc';
        return $this->from('me@myapp.com')->view('email.wantsheet.email_wantsheet_to_supplier', [])->subject($subject);
    }
}
```

**EDIT contd.**
Now when i do

`WantsheetProduct::orderByRaw(EmailService::WANTSHEET_PRODUCT_ORDER_SQL)->get()->toArray();`

it doesn't break the sorting any longer (so it works). But that is stupid, isn't it?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a collection preservation issue. Basically, if you change the order and you don't care about key names you also need to explicitly tell the collection that you've changed the order of keys in case you need to pass it on to something else. Try e.g. `->get()->values();`

Comment: @JoelHinz calling `->values()` before handing the object into the constructor doesnt seem to solve the issue, neither does `$this->wantsheet_products->values()` resort them the way they should be

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure so I only wrote it as a comment. Worth a shot. Hope somebody else can give you the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

When your mail object is queued for delivery, it takes your `Collection` of `Model` instances, gets their ids, and stores the list of ids on the queued job. When the queued job is then processed, it takes those Model ids, and retrieves the data from the database.

The problem, however, is that the query being run to rebuild the collection doesn't care about the order of the ids. It just runs a `whereIn()` statement with the list of ids.

Everything worked when you converted your Collection `toArray()` because it also converted all your Models to arrays. So, it was no longer a Collection of Models, it was an array of arrays. There is no special serialization that takes place there, so the data went across exactly as you sent it.

The easiest way to get your order back is probably to override the `restoreCollection` method, so you can add in your order by clause to the restoration query. Add this method to your `WantsheetToSuppliersMail` class:

```
protected function restoreCollection($value)
{
    if (! $value->class || count($value->id) === 0) {
        return new EloquentCollection;
    }

    $model = new $value->class;

    return $model->newQuery()->useWritePdo()
        ->whereIn($model->getKeyName(), $value->id)
        ->orderByRaw(EmailService::WANTSHEET_PRODUCT_ORDER_SQL)
        ->get();
}
```

This is the same as the current function, just that your custom order by has been applied to the query.

Comment: that's interesting.... but isn't this supposedly a bug? i mean a bug worth reporting? your fix looks quite non-trivial too, try to explain the code to someone who does not know why we have that there. What I ended up doing was remove `$wantsheet_products` from constructor, and rebuilding it in the `build(){}` function e.g. `build(){  $wantsheet_products = WantsheetProduct::orderByRaw(EmailService::WANTSHEET_PRODUCT_ORDER_SQL)->get();` but this means an SQL per Email! this is overhead for nothing, just because they screw up the order

Comment: @Toskan When you serialize eloquent models, there will always be a query per email, because the email needs to rebuild the models when the jobs are processed. If that is a concern, you may want to see if you can work with your original workaround of converting the models to arrays and passing that data into your mail object.

Comment: so when I say, not queue them but send them synchronously, i won't face that problem? e.g. instead of `->queue()` i use `->send() ` i.e. the mails won't be serialized?

Comment: @Toskan Yes, if you're not queuing the mail, it won't attempt to serialize the models. However, I would first try just removing the `SerializesModels` trait. That trait is what is causing the models to be converted to ids, and then back to models again. Without the trait, it will just directly serialize the entire model and pass it through. The order will be preserved and there will be no new query to re-fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

it is a known bug of laravel 5.3

basically reretrieve the objects in the build function e.g.

```
public function build()
{

  $this->wantsheet_products =  WantsheetProduct::orderByRaw(EmailService::WANTSHEET_PRODUCT_ORDER_SQL)->get();
  $subject = 'abc';
    return $this->from('me@myapp.com')->view('email.wantsheet.email_wantsheet_to_supplier', [])->subject($subject);
}
```